# dateadd - finding a date in the past

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I have an odd problem with subtracting 18 months from a date.
Consider the following snippet:

```
Convert(dateTime,CREATION_DATE,103) > 
    DateAdd (MONTH, -18, Convert (DateTime, @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE, 103))
```

This forms part of a where clause in a stored procedure. When I run:

```
exec theSP @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE = '21/02/2013'
```

it runs fine, but when I change it to this:

```
exec theSP @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE = '21/01/2013'
```

it breaks with the error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted  in an out-of-range value.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why it might be January (all other months are ok) that is breaking my code?

Thanks.

DS

Comment: What version of SQL are you running against?

Comment: Is `CREATION_DATE` varchar? WHY?

Comment: @aaron - it was being put into another database table that was varchar. not perfect, but it's a whole other issue!

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions folks. i managed to get the schema changed so i never had to bother with conversions to varchar.

Answer (score 2):

To pass string as datetime use `ISO format` as `yyyymmdd` which guaranteed to work in any server with any culture info.;

```
exec theSP @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE = '20130121'
```

Also as a side note,  *if `CREATION_DATE`* is already `datetime` then you don't need to `CONVERT CREATION_DATE` for comparison.

```
--if CREATION_DATE is DATETIME/DATE column
CREATION_DATE > 
DateAdd (MONTH, -18, Convert (DateTime, @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE))
```

Comment: your sidenote is the route i took. took some convincing to get the (eventually) receiving database's shema changed away from varchar! :)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the date in **YYYY-MM-DD** format.

Eg.:

```
exec theSP @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE = '2013-01-21'
```

Also, you can use [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to specify the date format:

Eg.:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
exec theSP @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE = '21/02/2013'
exec theSP @IN_ACTIVITY_DATE = '21/01/2013'
```

**SET DATEFORMAT:** Sets the order of the month, day, and year date parts for interpreting date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2 and datetimeoffset character strings.

```
SET DATEFORMAT { format | @format_var }
```

format | @format_var: Is the order of the date parts. Valid parameters are **mdy, dmy, ymd, ydm, myd, and dym**.

Comment: You should specify dates as YYYYMMDD, because YYYY-MM-DD is interpreted differently based on language: `set language french; select cast('2013-02-15' as datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

There might be something in your database, perhaps a `check constraint`, that doesn't like the January date. The conversion to seems to work on SQL Server 2008 ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/925e8/2)). Something else might be causing the problem.

Also, the date formatting suggestions provided by the others are good advice.